# What is the proper statistical test to apply for this scenario?

Tags: statistical-significance, biostatistics

I have measured the activity of an enzyme with two different substrates. I did this at 7 time points (t = 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 15, and 30 minutes). I repeated this experiment 3 times for each substrate and therefore have 6 tables of data. What is the appropriate statistical approach to take to determine whether or not for each time point the activity for one substrate is statistically different from the other.

In other words, how can I show that substrate a has a statistically significant difference in activity than substrate b with regards to each individual time point. I would greatly appreciate help!

I have tried looking up methods, but I get lost in some of the statistic jargon.

Comment: I would make mean comparison tests (like the T or KW-tests) between both enzymes at each time step. Unfortunatelly, with only 3 repetitions, the power of the test won't be that good

Comment: You can't be the first person to run an enzyme experiment like this. What techniques are they using in the biochemistry literature? We can help translate that into easier terms.

Comment: From further reading, it appears that the t-test is the most common. However, the exact type I am not sure of. I believe this would be considered a non-paired test. Am I right to think this? Also, there is non-paramatretic versus parametric statistics. I am unsure of which should be used for this data set. The literature article I have referenced only states they used the t-test with an alpha of 0.05.

Answer (score 0):

Start with plotting your data. It seems you would like a separate analysis for each time point? You are right that this is not paired data, so you should not use the paired t-test, use the independent samples t-test.

But doing seven separate analysis you are running into multiplicity problems, so maybe consider a two-way anova also.